# Python Classify commands

Tags: python, loops

I am writing a python script to classify ip countries as they are in another file .. for example .. I have 2 files in the script dir

IPCountries.txt contains :-

```
192.168.1.1   |    US,
188.100.0.0   |    AU,
```

and the file arrange.txt contains :-

```
0="US,CA,UK,GE,"
1="AU,EG,"
```

Now the script will read each line in IPCountries.txt file and take the value after "|" like the value "US" and then match it with the value in file arrange.txt and write it into a new file called 0.txt .

The problem is that i do not know how to do this but i have used some info to write the next code but i am stuck in the loop in the end of the code as u can see here ..

```
import re
import os
filepath = 'arrange.txt'
with open(filepath) as file:
    txt = file.read()
mapping = re.findall(r'(\d+)="(.*)"', txt)

ip = open("IPCountries.txt",'r')
for line in ip:
```

Any help with the loop or suggestion how to do it but in the same process and files ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You could use something like

```
for line in ip:
    ip, country = [e.strip() for e in line.split("|")]
    country = country[:-1] # Strip off comma at the end
```

I'm not sure what you intend to do with this variables, but the basic extraction process could look like my example code.

Comment: You are not calling `e.strip`.

Comment: @Javier Oh, wow, can't believe I copied the *wrong* line of code from the interactive interpreter ;-) Thanks for noting, I fixed that!

Comment: I tried to use this code but face this error

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./rr.py", line 11, in <module>
    ip, country = [e.strip() for e in line.split("|")]
ValueError: need more than 1 value to unpack

Comment: @abualameer94 Are really all the lines in your countries file in the format you described them in? The error msg looks like there is no `|` at all in the line !

Comment: Thanks , I found the problem it was in the first line for the file , but still one thing missing in the code i want the code to create a text file called 0.txt and enter the ip's that it's level is 0 .. depends in those 2 file

Comment: @abualameer94 I think, in all honesty, you should *really* try that yourself, else you won't ever learn python ;-) It's not that difficult!